# User login flow for Android app of RALLY

Tags: java, android, rally

I am using rally Rest API and developing a Rally app.I want to authenticate the user on the basis of Rally Credentials.I have managed to import the rally-rest-api-2.2.1.jar and HTTP jars.I am refering https://github.com/RallyTools/RallyRestToolkitForJava/wiki/User-Guide#setup

I have created a login page and tried to use the constructor.If the user name and password is correct it should navigate to the next page and I can further work on GET requests etc.

My code:

```
package com.example.apetkar.pocrally;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Credentials;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.rallydev.rest.client.BasicAuthClient;
import com.rallydev.rest.client.HttpClient;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText etemail;
EditText etpass;
Button btnlogin;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    etemail=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextemail);
    etpass=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextpassword);
    btnlogin=(Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonlogin);
    btnlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            try {
                getClient();



            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }


    });
}
public HttpClient getClient() throws MalformedURLException {
    try
    {
        BasicAuthClient basicAuthClient = new BasicAuthClient(new URI("https://rally1.rallydev.com"),etemail.getText().toString(),etpass.getText().toString());
        basicAuthClient.getServer();
        basicAuthClient.setApplicationName("Rally-Mobile");


        return basicAuthClient;
    }
    catch (URISyntaxException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
}
```

Can anyone suggest what should be the flow or how can I achieve this.Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to make a simple request in your try block to make sure the credentials are good.  Also, you should probably be instantiating a RallyRestApi rather than a BasicAuthClient directly.